# What is the most performant code for xml string to objects

Tags: .net, xml, parsing, c#-4.0, xml-parsing

I'm trying to optimize some existing code ( where speed is the primary criteria ) which loads an xml string into XmlDocument and then gets the values like so

```
XmlNodeList listaa = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("aa");
if (listaa.Count > 0)
                myObj.aa = Convert.ToDouble(listaa[0].InnerText);
```

and so on

while the above is obviously not the best approach, wondering if there's anything new in .net 4.0 that might improve the speed and perhaps readability as well

thanks

Note - the xml strings are approx 100-200 bytes in size so there's not really a whole lot of performance improvement using xmlreader vs. reading to a xmldocument !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [XML serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/182eeyhh.aspx). It's quite efficient because it generates serialization assemblies and reuses them (you can pre-generate the assemblies for better performance on the first run)

Answer (score 3):

The fastest approach is to use old and famous XmlReader. Though readability of your code will be worse but you will get the highest performance.

Comment: good point, didn't even think of that as the xml doc in this case is typically 100 bytes so not a whole lot of improvement to be had there, updated the question with this info !